# How to get single column value using hibernate projection

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a model class like below:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "User")
    public class UserModel implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 204096185700135310L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer userId;

@Column(name = "user_login_name")
private String userLoginName;

@Column(name = "user_email_id")
private String userEmailId;

@Column(name = "user_password")
private String userPassword;
```

}

and I am writting a criteria with projection to get the userLoginName based on userId, like SELECT user_login_name from USER where user_id=1 :

```
   public UserModel getUserByUserName(Integer userId) {
    return (UserModel) HibernateService.getSession(sessionFactory)
            .createCriteria(UserModel.class)
            .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                    .add(Projections.property("userLoginName"), "userLoginName"))
            .add(Restrictions.eq(AppConstant.USER_Id, userId))
            .uniqueResult();
}
```

But it's throwing **java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.app.aus.model.UserModel** excetion. can someone help me here

Comment: You cast the query result (that is the userLoginName which a String) to the *Entity* UserModel.
If you really want return the loginname then just don't cast. Of course, you should change method signature. If you instead want simply filter you don't  need to use projection

Comment: What kinda filter I can apply here with criteria?

Comment: Thnaks gtosto, it worked without casting